# VB.Net File Transfer: Incomplete Received Files

Tags: .net, vb.net, sockets, file-transfer

I have created a file sharing program in VB.Net, but when I try to send a file, the receiving part does not receive the file properly. Only part of the file I sent. Say, I sent a 100 MB file, only 10 MB will be received. Sometimes 22 KB, 39MB, etc. The size of the received file is not always the same. What do you think causes this problem? What should I do to properly receive the whole file?

**Sending part**

```
Sub Main()
    Dim ip As New IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 8888)' Port Server
    Dim sock As New Sockets.Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream,   ProtocolType.IP)' Protocol type
    sock.Bind(ip)
    sock.Listen(100)
    While True' Check Client Connection
        Try
           msg("Accept Client Connect")
           Dim csock As Sockets.Socket = sock.Accept
           Dim csend(1024 * 10000) As Byte
           Dim path As String = "C:\Users\IT\Desktop\test\" ' Location to save file
           Dim bLen As Integer = csock.Receive(csend) ' Byte Read Len
           Dim fileLen As Integer = BitConverter.ToInt32(csend, 0) ' File Len
           Dim fName As String = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(csend, 4, fileLen) ' File Name
           msg("Start Receive....." & fName)
           Dim bWrite As New BinaryWriter(File.Open(path + fName, FileMode.Append))
           bWrite.Write(csend, 4 + fileLen, bLen - 4 - fileLen)
           msg("File receiced and Save " & path)
           bWrite.Close()
           csock.Close()
       Catch ex As Exception
           msg(ex.Message)
       End Try
    End While
    Console.ReadLine()
End Sub

Sub msg(ByVal mesg As String)
mesg.Trim()
Console.WriteLine(" >> " + mesg)
End Sub
```

**Receiving Part**

```
Private Sub Button2_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)     Handles Button2.Click
    Dim ipServer As IPAddress() = Dns.GetHostAddresses("127.0.0.1") ' IP Server
    Dim ip As IPEndPoint = New IPEndPoint(ipServer(0), 8888)
    Dim csock As Socket = New Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream,     ProtocolType.IP)
    Dim fName As String = TextBox1.Text
    Dim path As String = TextBox2.Text
    Dim fNameByte() As Byte = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(fName)
    Dim fData() As Byte = File.ReadAllBytes(path & "\" & fName)
    Dim cData(4 + fName.Length + fData.Length) As Byte
    Dim fDataLen() As Byte = BitConverter.GetBytes(fNameByte.Length)
    Try
       fDataLen.CopyTo(cData, 0)
       fNameByte.CopyTo(cData, 4)
       fData.CopyTo(cData, 4 + fNameByte.Length)
       csock.Connect(ip)
       csock.Send(cData)
       MsgBox("Success Send File ")
       csock.Close()
    Catch ex As Exception
       MsgBox(ex.Message)
    End Try
End Sub

Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)  Handles Button1.Click
    If OpenFileDialog1.ShowDialog = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK Then
    TextBox1.Text = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(OpenFileDialog1.FileName)
    TextBox2.Text = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(OpenFileDialog1.FileName)
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: You hope that you'll get the entire file with only one Receive() call.  That will not work, you'll have to keep calling Receive() until you've received all the bytes.

Comment: Ok. Thanks for that. So, that means that I need to get the bytes by chunks. Just one more question, what is the maximum size of byte chunk that I can send over the network?

Comment: There are no chunks, TCP is a *stream*.  You'll get an unpredictable number of bytes with each Receive() call.  Sending it is easier, the Send() call will simply block until the bytes could be sent.  You normally use a loop where you read, say, 4096 bytes at a time from the file and Send() them.  Which is a good way to use very little memory and prevent crashing your program when the file is large.

Comment: Ok. I get the concept now. But how can I get the total file size on the receiving part? I mean, if I'm getting an unpredictable number of bytes, how will I be able to reconstruct the file if I don't know what is the total size of that file? Something like, `bytesRead < totalSize` that I can use as a condition for a conditional loop.

Comment: Nevermind. I get it. When there is no data read, meaning bytes read is equal to 0, then the loop on the receiving part must stop. Thanks for your time and suggestions. It really helped a lot! :)

Comment: No, that's not it, you only get 0 when the other end disconnected.  You already put it in your code but probably didn't realize it.  It is the number 4 appearing in your code.  You send the length as the first 4 bytes.  But you forgot the Receive call to read those 4 bytes.

Comment: Oh. Thanks for that. I think I should modify my code so that when the receiving part receives zero byte, it would signal that reading is complete.

Answer (score 0):

**mistake 1,**  a created the binary file with ***Append*** mode which should have been ***Create*** at ***line 07***
**mistake 2,**  A nested loop should have been used to receive the packet. here i add do ~ loop. a if condition check weather is another packet is available or not by check it size , if size=0 then exits the loop  at ***line 08 ~ 13*** 
**mistake 3,**  when the first packet is received, it was written in the file minus the meta data. like bWrite.Write(csend,4+fileLen,bLen-4-fileLen).***at Line 06/10*** This was fine for the first packet but not for the remaining packets.because the meta data is send only once at the beginning, so it shouldnt be removed from each and ever packet. the remain values should be 0 and the length of packet in this case bLen. as you can see at ***line 12*** i am reset these values.

```
         01,   Dim csock As Sockets.Socket = sock.Accept
         02,   Dim csend(1024 * 10000) As Byte
         03,   Dim bLen As Integer = csock.Receive(csend) ' Byte Read Len
         04,   Dim fileLen As Integer = BitConverter.ToInt32(csend, 0) ' File Len
         05,   Dim fName As String = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(csend, 4, fileLen) ' File Name
         06,   Dim strt As Integer = 4 + fileLen, ln As Integer = bLen - 4 - fileLen

         07,   Dim bWrite As New BinaryWriter(File.Open(path + fName, FileMode.Create))
         08,   Do
         09,       If bLen = 0 Then Exit Do
         10,       bWrite.Write(csend, strt, ln)
         11,       bLen = csock.Receive(csend) ' Byte Read Len
         12,       strt = 0 : ln = bLen
         13,   Loop
```

sorry i try to explain it as best as i could.